# Regex patterns in Java vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have java Regex pattern for UK Postcode:

```
^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$
```

I want to use it in Javascript as well but it does not validate Postcodes correctly in Javascript.
Is there any difference between Regex patterns in Java and Javascript?

Comment: What is the format of UK's postal code, give us the pattern that you would like to search?

Comment: It works in js for "DE56 2SR". What postal code do you have that it is not working with?

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between Java and JavaScript regex flavors: JS does not support lookbehind.

A tabulation of differences between regex flavors can be [found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features).

However, this does not apply to your case. I surmise that your JS test string has spurious characters, eg. cr/lf.

Try to use the regex without the anchors and check the lengths of the test strings.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex works just as well in JavaScript as Java. Below is a short example using some data I made up.

```js
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/;

var testData = [

  // valid
  'A11 1AA',
  'a1 1aa',
  'Aa1a 1AA',
  'aA11 1aa',
  'Aa1 1AA',

  // invalid
  'aa1aa 1aa',
  '@a11 1aa',
  'a1aa 1aa'
];

for (var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
  if (testData[i].match(regex)) {
    console.log(testData[i] + ' is valid.');
  } else {
    console.log(testData[i] + ' is invalid.');
  }
}
```

Bonus tips:

You could simplify your regex some. The `{1}` is unnecessary, and you don't need to wrap the space in `[]`.

```
 ^[a-zA-Z]([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]) [0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]$
```

Of course, you can leave in any `()` that you want for capture groups, but I don't know if you are using those.